# Threading the same function for a different result in Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, module, python-multithreading

I need my program to execute a certain function in parallel. But that function branches off into different results depending on how the user interacts with the program. I have a simple GUI within a module named threadGUI.py that has two options: Downloading and uploading. These options create dictionaries containing variables related to the function. These dictionaries are stored in a main dictionary which is stored in the thread_test.py module. These work fine when executing one after the other, but when I try to do it in parallel something goes wrong.
The threading related code in threadGUI.py:

```
def OnStartClick(self):
  for i in thread_test.dictList.values():        #the main dictionary is stored as a global in thread_test.py
     thread = Thread(target = thread_test.begin_tests, args = (i, ))
     thread.start()
  print "thread finished...exiting"
```

The above function calls the begin_test function within the thread_test.py module. The function looks like so:

```
def begin_tests(arg): 
    print arg
    print dictList
    dictItem = arg
    print dictItem
    if dictItem['Type'] == "HTTP_Downloading":
        print "DOWNLOAD"
    elif dictItem['Type'] == "FTP_Uploading":
        print "UPLOAD"
    else:
        print "Invalid input"
        sys.exit(1)
```

This is a simplified example of my code. My problem is that my code is only executing one function out of the two instead of both. So if I created a dictionary which called a download, upload, download then it would execute three downloads, instead of the desired pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the code posted:

```
from threading import Thread

dictList = {
    'foo': { 'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading' },
    'bar': { 'Type': 'FTP_Uploading' },
    'baz': { 'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading' }
}

def begin_tests(arg):
    print arg
    print dictList
    dictItem = arg
    print dictItem
    if dictItem['Type'] == "HTTP_Downloading":
        print "DOWNLOAD"
    elif dictItem['Type'] == "FTP_Uploading":
        print "UPLOAD"
    else:
        print "Invalid input"
        sys.exit(1)

def OnStartClick(self):
  for i in dictList.values():        #the main dictionary is stored as a global in thread_test.py
     thread = Thread(target = begin_tests, args = (i, ))
     thread.start()
  print "thread finished...exiting"

OnStartClick(None)
```

Results in:

```
{'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}
{'baz': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'foo': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'bar': {'Type': 'FTP_Uploading'}}
{'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}
 {DOWNLOAD
{'Type': 'FTP_Uploading'}
'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}
{'baz': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'foo': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'bar': {'Type': 'FTP_Uploading'}}
{'baz': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'foo': {'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}, 'bar': {'Type': 'FTP_Uploading'}}
 thread finished...exiting
{'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading'}
DOWNLOAD
{'Type': 'FTP_Uploading'}
UPLOAD
```

At a guess, the you are reusing the inner dict.

UPDATE:

I think this case is better solved by using a worker-pool-and-queue strategy. Something like:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

queue = Queue() # Replaces the dictList

threads = []
for n in range(10):
    thread = Thread(target = worker, args = (begin_tests, queue, ))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

Stop = object()
def worker(work, queue):
    while True:
        task = queue.get()
        if task is Stop:
            break
        work(task)
```

Use it like so:

```
queue.put({ 'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading' })
queue.put({ 'Type': 'FTP_Uploading' })
queue.put({ 'Type': 'HTTP_Downloading' })
queue.put(Stop)
```

This does not in itself address the problem of mutating the dicts; that has to be fixed elsewhere. This strategy has two benefits: it does preserve the order of tasks and it does not risk losing tasks: dict makes limited concurrency guarantees, whereas Queue() is guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: I came to that realization soon after posting my question so your guess is right. I currently don't know how to go about a work around though. Once the next thread starts it overwrites the dictItem and causes errors in any previous ongoing threads.
Is there any way to fix a global variable to that specific thread instead of affecting all of them?

Comment: The queues sound great but this program is too far gone to switch over right now. Maybe if I have time at the end to optimize the code I can give them a go.
It turned out I was messing with global variables too much and I discovered local threading storage which solved my issue. Thanks for your help anyway, it helped me narrow down the issue!